# HttpWebRequest use VPN(just like proxy)

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, vpn

So my question is if there is possibility to use VPN instead of Proxy in HttpWebRequest? I need to make voting program, but all public proxies are slow or unreliable.

Just like this:

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8080);
```

Comment: Why not use a external VPN tool and just connect via the IP it provieds?

Comment: I need to vote from for example 200 different IPs